# Assign roles to wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

My custom post_type  `circular` and custom role `circular_uploader` and `capabilities` is not working please help me to short it out. Now they are show like post capabilities but I need to make the unique

```
 Create posts
 Delete others posts
 Delete posts
 Delete private posts
 Delete published posts
 Edit others posts
 Edit posts
 Edit private posts
 Edit published posts
 Publish posts
 Read private posts
```

**The above capabilities need to change like bellow capabilities**

```
 Create circulars
 Delete others circulars
 Delete circulars
 Delete private circulars
 Delete published circulars
 Edit others circulars
 Edit circulars
 Edit private circular
 Edit published circulars
 Publish circulars
 Read private circulars
```

**And my custom post type**

```
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our circulars and circular specific data',
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'excerpt' ),
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-unlink',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
      'create_post'          => 'create_circular', 
      'edit_post'          => 'edit_circular', 
      'read_post'          => 'read_circular', 
      'delete_post'        => 'delete_circular', 
      'edit_posts'         => 'edit_circulars', 
      'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_circulars', 
      'publish_posts'      => 'publish_circulars',       
      'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_circulars', 
      'create_posts'       => 'create_circulars', 
    ),
  );
  register_post_type( 'circular', $args ); 
}
```

**Adding a custom role**

```
add_role("circular_uploader", "Circular Uploader", array(
    'read' => true,
    'upload_files'=>true,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'edit_pages' => false,
    'edit_others_posts' => false,
    'create_posts' => false,
    'manage_categories' => false,
    'publish_posts' => false,
    'edit_themes' => false,
    'install_plugins' => false, 
    'update_plugin' => false,
    'update_core' => false, 
    'create_circular' => true,
    'edit_circular' => true,
    'edit_others_circular' => true,
    'delete_circular' => true,
    'delete_others_circular' => true,
    'publish_circular' => true
));
```

**Assign capabilities to role**

```
function add_circular_caps() {

 // gets the administrator role register_activation_hook
    $roles = get_role( 'circular_uploader' );

    $roles ->add_cap( 'create_circular' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'edit_circular' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'edit_circulars' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'edit_other_circulars' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'publish_circulars' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'read_circular' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'read_private_circulars' ); 
    $roles ->add_cap( 'delete_circular' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_circular_caps');
```

Comment: look the result `get_post_type_object("circular")->cap`. you need to give other capabilites to the role to give all rights.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using plugin for this, [User Role Editor](https://fi.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) works great.

Comment: Yes I know but that was not my question answer